# How do I translate a typedef callback with named params?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

So I'm given a header line like this:

```
typedef PVOID   (WINAPI *GDIMARSHALLOC)(DWORD dwSize, __in LPVOID pGdiRef);
```

How can I maintain the param names/flags without calling the prototype?

The only thing I know how to do is something like this:

```
GDIMARSHALLOC = POINTER(CALLBACK(PVOID, DWORD, LPVOID))
```

note that `CALLBACK` is a custom definition, similar to `WINFUNCTYPE`.

Comment: The names don't matter in a prototype, only the types.  What isn't working for you?

Comment: It's not so much what isn't working so much as it is what I can do to even get names provided (I would prefer it for completeness), is it possible at all or does ctypes simply lack the support?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify *paramflags* when you instantiate a CFUNCTYPE/WINFUNCTYPE prototype, but can't specify parameter names , but I don't see how that helps with a callback since that would be called outside your code.

See the bottom of [Function Prototypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#function-prototypes]) in the `ctypes` documentation for the discussion on *paramflags*.

Here's an example from that documentation:

```
>>> from ctypes import c_int, WINFUNCTYPE, windll
>>> from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPCWSTR, UINT
>>> prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT)
>>> paramflags = (1, "hwnd", 0), (1, "text", "Hi"), (1, "caption", "Hello from ctypes"), (1, "flags", 0)
>>> MessageBox = prototype(("MessageBoxW", windll.user32), paramflags)
```

> The MessageBox foreign function can now be called in these ways:

```
>>> MessageBox()
>>> MessageBox(text="Spam, spam, spam")
>>> MessageBox(flags=2, text="foo bar")
```

Comment: Right, sadly this isn't really an answer, but it is good information readily available for others... But I need the paramflags basically supplied with the prototype itself rather than an instance of the prototype. And btw, a minor note about python's poor documentation, paramflag entry type 3 (inout) isn't mentioned.

Comment: @Tcll Well, it is an answer. The answer is you can’t do it to a prototype, just an instance of one.  Also the docs say these are param flags that can be combined, so 3 is 1+2, or inout.

Comment: @Tcll You could always *comment* the prototype. In C, instances of a typedef don’t have to match the parameters names in the typedef either, so they basically are like a comment there too.  I generally put a comment about the C prototype I’m wrapping anyway, so future users can judge if it was wrapped correctly.

Comment: Fair enough, or doc-comment, which might be better if an IDE supports dynamic `__doc__` access. Thanks for helping me understand, I'll answer this with my own mechanism of nobody beats me to it. :)